# Correct usage of typing types for args and kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pycharm

```
def callable_runner(a_callable: Callable[..., Any], args: Sequence[Any]=None, kwargs: Mapping[Any, Any]=None) -> None:
    if args is None:
        args = []
    if kwargs is None:
        kwargs = {}
    a_callable(*args, **kwargs)
```

I feel like this is probably a correct usage, but I'm not sure because I haven't completely grasped types yet.

What is making me doubt myself is Pycharm gives me a warning on `*args` that says `Expected an iterable, got Sequence | None | list` and a warning on `**kwargs` that says `Expected a dictionary, got Mapping | None | dict`.

I lean towards PyCharm being wrong to raise a warning here, but I'm not very confident.

Comment: Aren't you just missing the `*` and `**` in the function signature?

Comment: @cheapner, I don't think so?  I'm not wanting to use the args/kwargs as arguments to `callable_runner` but as arguments to `a_callable`.

Comment: Using `typing.Union`: `def callable_runner(a_callable: Callable[..., Any], args: Union[Sequence[Any], None]=None, kwargs: Union[Mapping[Any, Any], None]=None) -> None:` ?

Comment: @falsetru, Yes, that kills the warning (you can also use `typing.Optional` instead of Union-ing), but the [typing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) say the Optional should be inferred if you use a default of None.