# Specifying *args for a Callable type hint

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

What's the best way to specify that the Callable variable `fn` takes `*my_args` as arguments? Like this:

```py
def test(fn: Callable([Tuple[any]], None),
         *my_args: any) -> None:
    fn(*myargs)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type annotations for \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Not really, at most it could be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725072/correct-usage-of-typing-types-for-args-and-kwargs), but it's unanswered

Comment: Type hinting only provides information about how `fn` *can* be used, not how it *is* used.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the documentation on [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

> There is no syntax to indicate optional or keyword arguments; such function types are rarely used as callback types. `Callable[..., ReturnType]` (literal ellipsis) can be used to type hint a callable taking any number of arguments and returning `ReturnType`.

So in your case where `*args` is optional and `ReturnType` is `None`, use

```
fn: Callable[..., None]
```

P.s. I don't use type hints so please let me know if I've misunderstood anything.

Answer (score 25):

Now with [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) in Python 3.10, you can write this:

```py
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")


def test(fn: Callable[P, None], *my_args: P.args, **my_kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
    fn(*myargs, **my_kwargs)
```

Then any calls to `test` will be properly type checked.