# Type annotation for the arguments of a function

Tags: python, python-typing

Please take a look at the following example:

```
from typing import TypeVar
from collections.abc import Callable

T0 = TypeVar("T0")
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

def my_fun(a: str, b: int) -> None:
    print(int(a) + b)
    return None

def fun_caller(f: Callable[[T0, T1], T2], *args: tuple[T0, T1]) -> T2:
    return f(*args)

fun_caller(my_fun, "1", 2)
```

I want to pass a function followed by the arguments of that function to another function.
The example above works as the type checker knows that the correct number of arguments and correct argument types are being used in `fun_caller(my_fun, "1", 2)`. However, this example only works for functions with exactly 2 input arguments, and I would like to generalize this for any number of arguments of unknown types.

Also note the following example:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Any
from collections.abc import Callable

T = TypeVar("T")

def my_fun(a: str, b: int) -> None:
    print(int(a) + b)
    return None

def fun_caller(f: Callable[..., T], *args: tuple[Any, ...]) -> T:
    return f(*args)

fun_caller(my_fun, 0, 2, "a") # I want the type checker to complain, e.g.,
                              # first arg should be str
                              # there should only be 2 args, not 3
```

This does not work since now the type checker won't complain about the invalid number of arguments and invalid argument types. This code will raise `TypeError: my_fun() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`, as expected, but I would like to capture this problem in the type checker.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no, something like that is shown in my second example, and I go into why I want something different

Comment: There are multiple answers to that question, one of them recommends using `ParamSpec` have a look at that one...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814270/5666087 specifically. And take a look at PEP 612 which you can use with Python 3.10+. If you're using an older version of Python, I'm afraid this might not be possible.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you are right, I missed the second answer, which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that this can be achieved with [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec). Example:

```
# pyright: strict

from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar
from collections.abc import Callable

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

def my_fun1(a: str, b: int) -> None:
    print(int(a) + b)
    return None

def my_fun2(a: str, b: int, c: float) -> None:
    print(int(a) + b*c)
    return None

def fun_caller(f: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

fun_caller(my_fun1, "1", 2)             # no issues reported
fun_caller(my_fun2, "1", 2, 3.14)       # no issues reported
fun_caller(my_fun2, c=3.14, a="1", b=2) # no issues reported
fun_caller(my_fun1, 0, 2, "a")          # Argument of type "Literal[0]" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "str"
                                        # Expected 2 positional arguments
```